# pyplot changing colors of legend text in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would figure out how to mange the fonts(colors ...) in the legend of the sub plot .. for a single plot I do

```
legend = leg = self.axs[i,j].legend()
legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(1.2)
plt.setp(legend.get_texts(), color='#555555')
```

but in subplot `axs[i,j].setp(....)` give me the error

`self.axs[i,j].setp(legend.get_texts(), color='#555555')
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'setp'`
 
**EDIT** doen't works for subplot .. sorry I mean that works only if I call it from the client .. not from the wrapper class
**EDIT** can I write here the whole wrappers and you say me what do you think ?

Comment: The code you show seems to work fine. What's the problem with it?

Comment: You can use exactly the working code anywhere. (I'm not sure what the "client" and "wrapper class" are.)